# Why do I keep getting two exceptions: Slope Limit must be smaller than 90 degrees and offset must be less?

Tags: unity, c#

The two exceptions/errors in the editor:

Slope Limit must be smaller than 90 degrees
Step Offset must be less or equal to  +  * 2

In the Hierarchy I have a a First Person Character named Player under it as child a Player Camera and as child of the Player Camera a NAVI object.

I changed in the Inspector the NAVI scale to 0.01 on XYZ:

[image: Scaling]

And I have another empty gameobject in the hierarchy with a script attached to it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectsManipulation : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Camera
    public Camera playerCamera;

    //Scaling
    private Scaling scaling;

    //Lights
    public DimLights dimlights;
    private Coroutine lightCoroutine;

    //Colors
    private Colors colors;

    //Rotating
    public bool stopRotation = false;
    private Rotating rotating;

    private void Start()
    {
        scaling = GetComponent<Scaling>();
        scaling.Inits();

        colors = GetComponent<Colors>();
        colors.Start();

        rotating = GetComponent<Rotating>();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Update()
    {
        //Scaling
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            //Flip the scale direction when F key is pressed
            scaling.scaleUp = !scaling.scaleUp;

            //Stop old coroutine
            if (scaling.scaleCoroutine != null)
                StopCoroutine(scaling.scaleCoroutine);

            if (lightCoroutine != null)
                StopCoroutine(lightCoroutine);


            //Scale  up
            if (scaling.scaleUp)
            {
                //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
                rotating.rotateBack = false;
                scaling.scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaling.scaleOverTime(scaling.objectToScale, scaling.maxSize, scaling.duration));
                if (dimlights.lightsOnOff == false)
                    lightCoroutine = StartCoroutine(dimlights.dimLightOverTime(1, scaling.duration));
            }

            //Scale Down
            else
            {
                //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
                rotating.rotateBack = true;
                scaling.scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaling.scaleOverTime(scaling.objectToScale, scaling.minSize, scaling.duration));
                if (dimlights.lightsOnOff == false)
                    lightCoroutine = StartCoroutine(dimlights.dimLightOverTime(0, scaling.duration)); ;
            }
        }

        //Rotate
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R) && !scaling.scaleUp)
        {
            rotating.x += Time.deltaTime * rotating.rotationSpeed;
            scaling.objectToScale.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotating.x);
            rotating.keyPressed = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.R))
        {
            rotating.keyPressed = false;
        }

        if (!rotating.keyPressed && !scaling.scaleUp && rotating.rotateBack == false
            && DetectInteractable.detected == false)
        {
            scaling.objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerCamera.transform.forward);
        }

        if (DetectInteractable.detected == true && !scaling.scaleUp && stopRotation == false)
        {
            rotating.x += Time.deltaTime * rotating.rotationSpeed;
            scaling.objectToScale.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotating.x);
        }
    }
}
```

In this script in the Inspector in the Scaling part I changed the Min Size on xyz also to 0.01

Since then Im getting this exceptions.

[image: Scaling]

Tried to google for a solution , But not sure how to fix it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Take your player avatar object that you want to scale down and break it into two parts:

1. A top-level container object you can think of as your "logical avatar." This object should have its scale set to (1, 1, 1). It will be used for any gameplay behaviours the avatar needs to interact with, including:

   - hosting the character controller component
   - being the target of any scripts that need to reference the player avatar
2. A child "visual" object that contains your character's mesh and any animation components it needs. You can scale this object however you want without interfering with the physics & gameplay logic handled higher up at its parent.

Separating the gameplay & visual parts of your objects can give you a lot more flexibility to iterate with appearances, feedback, and scales without mucking up your physics & play logic.